# Tableau worksheet not updating after editing BigQuery Custom SQL using Extract Data

Tags: tableau-api

I have a custom SQL code (BigQuery as a datasource) with date starting from Jan-2020, using extract data. Now when I modified the code to include date from 2019 onwards in addition to 2020, my worksheets are not updated. Even after doing "EXTRACT REFRESH" or replacing the data source i.e. It still shows 2020 data only and not 2019 data. The code is correct when checked in BQ.

But when I use the revised code in a new worksheet with extract connection, it shows 2019 data correctly.

Can someone please tell, what could be the reason for data not getting refreshed?

Comment: Hard to tell without more detail, but are you saving your file as a workbook (TWB file) or a packaged workbook (TWBX file)? If you are using TWBX, try TWB instead. Save packaged workbooks contain a copy of the data rather than a reference to it.

Comment: Hello Alex, thank you for the reply. But I did not understand your reply correctly this part (Save packaged workbooks contain a copy of the data rather than a reference to it.), Sorry. Mine was a twbx file and now saved as TWB. But what next you recommend, can you please guide?

Comment: By making a TWB file instead of a TWBX file you removed one possible source of the confusion. Now see if it it works correctly with the extract disabled, then if so refresh the extract and see if the problem still exists. Make sure you know where the extract is stored, see Extract->Properties